# XSLT condition compare attributes between different elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Considering the XML file:

```
 <collection>

    <director id="d1">
      <name>Michael Bay</name>
    </director>

    <director id="d2">

      <name>Quentin Tarantino</name>

    </director>

    <movie directors="d1">
      <title>Explosions</title>
    </movie>

    <movie directors="d1 d2">
      <title>Blood and Explosions</title>
    </movie>

 </collection>
```

I want the XSLT (XSLT 1.0) to transform it to a list of all the directors with a sublist of all the films they directed.

It should be something like:

```
    <ul>
      <li>Quentin Tarantino
        <ul><li>Blood and Explosions</li></ul>
      </li>
      <li>Michael Bay
        <ul>
         <li>Explosions</li>
         <li>Blood and Explosions</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I tried using the for-each and if statements, but I don't know how to compare @id and @directors.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
        <body>
            <h3>Directors</h3>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>


</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="director">

    <xsl:for-each select="//movie">

    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XSLT you have tried so far, as a starting point? Also, can you say whether you can use XSLT 2.0 or above? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you are looking for to select the movies for the director is this..

```
<xsl:for-each select="../movie[contains(concat(' ', @directors, ' '), concat(' ', current()/@id, ' '))]">
```

The use of concat here is to avoid where you might have an director of `d12` for a movie, so you want to avoid `d1` being matched for it (as `d12` contains `d1`)

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/collection">
  <html>
    <body>
      <h3>Directors</h3>
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="director" />
      </ul>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="director">
  <li>
    <xsl:value-of select="name" />     
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="../movie[contains(concat(' ', @directors, ' '), concat(' ', current()/@id, ' '))]">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="title" />
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Note the use of `<xsl:apply-templates select="director" />` because otherwise your use of `<xsl:apply-templates />` would select all child nodes, and due to the XSLT's built-in templates you would end up with the text in `movie` being output where you didn't want it).

If you could use XSLT 2.0, you could make use of a `xsl:key` to simplify things though:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:key name="movies" match="movie" use="tokenize(@directors, ' ')" />

<xsl:template match="/collection">
  <html>
    <body>
      <h3>Directors</h3>
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="director" />
      </ul>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="director">
  <li>
    <xsl:value-of select="name" />     
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('movies', @id)">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="title" />
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```